# Is it possible to add kerning to a TextField in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

To match a Styleguide I have to add kerning to a textfield, both placeholder and value itself.

With UIKit I was able to do so with:

```swift
    class MyTextField: UITextField {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // ...

        self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: self.placeholder ?? "", attributes: [
            //...
            NSAttributedString.Key.kern: 0.3
        ])

        self.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "", attributes: [
            // ...
            NSAttributedString.Key.kern: 0.3
        ])
    }
}
```

In SwiftUI, I could figure out that I could apply a kerning effect to a `Text` element like so:

```swift
    Text("My label with kerning")
       .kerning(0.7)
```

Unfortunately, I could not find a way to apply a kerning style to neither a TextField's value nor placeholder. Any ideas on this one? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you need a UIKit view, use UIViewRepresentable.

Comment: @matt I already had the view implemented in SwiftUI and wanted to stick with it. It's not possible to use just a sole UITextField subclass **inside** a SwiftUI view, is it?

Comment: Yes; that's exactly what you can do, using UIViewRepresentable. SwiftUI views can live inside UIViews, and UIViews can live inside SwiftUI views.

Answer (score 5):

There is a simple tutorial on [HackingwithSwift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-wrap-a-custom-uiview-for-swiftui) that shows how to implement a UITextView. It can easily be adapted for UITextField.

Here is a quick example showing how to use `UIViewRepresentable` for you `UITextField`. Setting the kerning on both the text and the placeholder.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        MyTextField(text: $text, placeholder: "Placeholder")
    }

}

struct MyTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    var placeholder: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        return UITextField()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: self.placeholder, attributes: [
            NSAttributedString.Key.kern: 0.3
        ])
        uiView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: self.text, attributes: [
            NSAttributedString.Key.kern: 0.3
        ])
    }
}
```

---

#### Update

The above doesn't work for setting the kerning on the attributedText. Borrowing from the fantastic work done by Costantino Pistagna in his [medium article](https://medium.com/@valv0/textfield-and-uiviewrepresentable-46a8d3ec48e2) we need to do a little more work.

Firstly we need to create a wrapped version of the `UITextField` that allows us access to the delegate methods.

```
class WrappableTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {
    var textFieldChangedHandler: ((String)->Void)?
    var onCommitHandler: (()->Void)?

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if let nextField = textField.superview?.superview?.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1) as? UITextField {
            nextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        return false
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if let currentValue = textField.text as NSString? {
            let proposedValue = currentValue.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
            print(proposedValue)
            self.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: currentValue as String, attributes: [
                NSAttributedString.Key.kern: 10
            ])
            textFieldChangedHandler?(proposedValue as String)
        }
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        onCommitHandler?()
    }
}
```

As the `shouldChangeCharactersIn` delegate method will get called every time the text changes, we should use that to update the `attributedText` value. I tried using first the `proposedVale` but it would double up the characters, it works as expected if we use the `currentValue`

Now we can use the `WrappedTextField` in the `UIViewRepresentable`.

```
struct SATextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    private let tmpView = WrappableTextField()

    //var exposed to SwiftUI object init
    var tag:Int = 0
    var placeholder:String?
    var changeHandler:((String)->Void)?
    var onCommitHandler:(()->Void)?

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SATextField>) -> WrappableTextField {
        tmpView.tag = tag
        tmpView.delegate = tmpView
        tmpView.placeholder = placeholder
        tmpView.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: self.placeholder ?? "", attributes: [
            NSAttributedString.Key.kern: 10
        ])
        tmpView.onCommitHandler = onCommitHandler
        tmpView.textFieldChangedHandler = changeHandler
        return tmpView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WrappableTextField, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SATextField>) {
        uiView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        uiView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
    }
}
```

We set the attributed text for the placeholder in the `makeUIView`. The placeholder text is not being updated so we don't need to worry about changing that.

And here is how we use it:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        SATextField(tag: 0, placeholder: "Placeholder", changeHandler: { (newText) in
            self.text = newText
        }) {
            // do something when the editing of this textfield ends
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Meh… actually, it works fine, but I can't get the inner padding to work… [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47583605/5743350) used to work fine for me :(

Comment: :) I am glad the kerning is now working for you. If you have a question that is unrelated to kerning then I would suggest writing it up into a new question so that you can clearly express everything that you need to do, as the comments on SO do not really allow a detailed discussion to take place. For one, code does not format nicely here; and secondly, you are limited to 600 characters, so it makes it hard to express oneself fully.

Comment: Ive used this solution but there is a problem when setting a color to black.
The current character wont change color until the next one is pressed. 
any solutions in mind for this?

Comment: @RomanSterlin I am able to change the color of the text without issue. If you are having difficulties I would suggest that you write a new question with what you have tried and what isn't working. Unfortunately comments are not suitable or encouraged for extended discussion.